# About synchronization

Tags: java

i've doubt about synchronization where caching result of invoking method,
pseudo-code as followed

```
Cache cache = cacheMap.get("cacheKey"); // get implemented synchronization
if(cache!=null){
   return cache;
}
result = invokeLongTimeMethod();  //this method is thread-safe
map.put("cacheKey",result);  // put implemented synchronzization as well.
```

invokeLongTimeMethod() need to be wrapped using keyword(sychronized)? as followed

```
sychronized(this){
   result=invokeLongTimeMethod(); //notice: this method can be invoked more than one time 
}
```

i think that it don't add sychronized code has better performance seemingly.

Comment: Please ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how bad is to call the `invokeLongTimeMethod` twice in parallel.

Indeed, without synchronization the two threads close in time may both start calculating the value long way after failing to find the cached entry. However if  `invokeLongTimeMethod` is safe to call in parallel, both returned values are identical enough for the task and calls have no important side effects, this seems only marginally less efficient. One of the two computed values will be cached for the future.

However if the conditions above are not true, you need to synchronize to suspend one thread while another is already computing the missing value for the cache.